# Índice composto - M:N no Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, índices

Preciso adicionar um índice duplo à relação N para N, da tabela `courses_internships`. seria mais ou menos como isso: `add_index[:course_id, :internship_id]`.

Contudo, quando eu criei a tabela de ligação, o índice estava separado pelas colunas, não como o índice sendo as duas. Como posso reverter esta situação?

E ah, eu utilizo o método `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Comment: Ok, você precisa remover o index antigo e criar outro certo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu index novo será algo como: (se não precisar que ele seja único, apenas remova o `unique: true` da linha).

```
add_index :courses_internships, [:course_id, :internship_id], unique: true
```

Já para remover e adicionar os indexes , você pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
$ rails g migration remove_separated_indexes_and_add_new_to_course_internships
```

e então editar a classe de migration com algo do tipo:

```
class RemoveSeparatedIndexesAndAddNewToCourseInternships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :courses, :course_id
    remove_index :internships, :internship_id
    add_index :courses_internships, [:course_id, :internship_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Valeuu!

Comment: Valeu cara, deu certinho :)